# Lista pasta e subpastas em um foreach PHP

Tags: php, funções

Estou utilizando a biblioteca [BDecode](https://www.phpclasses.org/package/3473-PHP-Parse-and-extract-metadata-from-BitTorrent-files.html) para extrair informações de um arquivo `.torrent`, a ideia e lista as informações dos arquivos do torrent em uma tabela usando o *foreach*, entretanto durante a listagem, os arquivos que estão dentro de um diretório não aparecem como deveriam, aparece apenas o caminho até o arquivo.

- A biblioteca [BDecode](https://www.phpclasses.org/package/3473-PHP-Parse-and-extract-metadata-from-BitTorrent-files.html) centraliza as informações dos arquivos e das pastas em um `array multidimensional`.
- Removi as class pra encurtar o código.
- Vou deixa a source do projeto no [github](https://github.com/groupunknown/filedirectory) para quem quiser da uma olhada mais a fundo.

Como aparece:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como poderia deixar assim, fazendo os arquivos seguir o diretório e os sub diretórios:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exibir a primeira pasta e lista os arquivos dentro, assim por diante.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope='col'>ARQUIVOS</th>
            <th scope='col'>TAMANHO</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
<?php if(isset($torrent->result['info']['files'])) {
    foreach($torrent->result['info']['files'] as $file) {
    echo "<tr><td>
    <a>".extension(implode('\\',$file['path']))."</a>".implode('\\',$file['path'])."</td>
    <td>".$file['length'])."</td></tr>";
    } ?>
    <?php } else { 
    echo "<tr><td>".$torrent->result['info']['name']."</td>
    <td>".$torrent->result['info']['length']."</td></tr>";
    } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Criei esses scripts para rodar o `result` do `BDECODE` e criar uma array, talvez uma dessas opções te ajude. =D

---

Essa opção cria uma array onde a `key` é o path do arquivo.

```
require_once 'BDecode.php';
$tor = new BDECODE('file.torrent');

$dir = [];
foreach( $tor->result['info']['files'] as $file ){
    $filename = array_pop($file['path'] );

    /// key inicial 
    $key = "/"; 

    /// gera a $key baseado no path
    if( count($file['path']) ) 
        $key .= implode("/",$file['path']);

    /// cria $key na array caso não exista
    if( !isset($dir[$key]) ) $dir[$key] = [];

    /// adiciona um novo arquivo na $key
    array_push($dir[$key],$filename);
    /// array_push($dir[$key], [ $filename, $file['length'] ] );
}
```

Saida:

```
Array
(
    [/] => Array
        (
            [0] => [rvarun7777 rips] Follow me if you like my encodes!!!!!.txt
            [1] => Customized Folder View 1.PNG
            [2] => Customized Folder View.PNG
        )

    [/Extras/[Spoiler] Alternate Ending [Official]] => Array
        (
            [0] => Breaking Bad' Alternate Ending Is a Dream Come True _rvarun7777.mp4
        )

    [/Extras] => Array
        (
            [0] => Box Set Cover 2.jpg
            [1] => Box Set Cover.jpg
        )

    [/Extras/Breaking Bad Memes] => Array
        (
            [0] => Breaking Bad Memes_rvarun7777 (1).jpg
            [1] => Breaking Bad Memes_rvarun7777 (2).jpg
            [2] => Breaking Bad Memes_rvarun7777 (3).jpg
            [3] => Breaking Bad Memes_rvarun7777 (4).jpg
            [4] => Breaking Bad Memes_rvarun7777 (5).jpg
            [5] => Breaking Bad Memes_rvarun7777 (6).jpg
            [6] => Breaking Bad Memes_rvarun7777 (7).jpg
            [7] => Breaking Bad Memes_rvarun7777 (8).jpg
        )

...
```

---

Essa opção criar um array de arrays. 
<sup>Tentativa de simular um diretório. =P</sup>

```php
require_once 'BDecode.php';
$tor = new BDECODE('file.torrent');

function recursiveDir($path,&$dirbase ){

    if( count($path) > 1 )
    {
        /// criar diretorio com o nome
        $dirname = array_shift($path);
        if( !isset($dirbase[ $dirname ]) ) $dirbase[ $dirname ] = []; /// criar o diretorio caso nao exista
        recursiveDir( $path, $dirbase[ $dirname ] );  /// chama novamente para criar subdirs, e adicionar arquivos
    }
    else
    {
        /// pode se criar uma key ( Ex.: '.' ou 'files' ) ou apenas array_push no arquivo
        /// array_push( $dirbase, array_shift($path) );
        if( !isset($dirbase['.']) ) $dirbase['.'] = [];
        array_push( $dirbase['.'], array_shift($path) ); // guarda o arquivo na array de key '.'
    }
}

$dir = [];
foreach( $tor->result['info']['files'] as $file ){
    recursiveDir( $file['path'] , $dir );
}

print_r($dir);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [.] => Array
        (
            [0] => [rvarun7777 rips] Follow me if you like my encodes!!!!!.txt
            [1] => Customized Folder View 1.PNG
            [2] => Customized Folder View.PNG
        )

    [Extras] => Array
        (
            [[Spoiler] Alternate Ending [Official]] => Array
                (
                    [.] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Breaking Bad' Alternate Ending Is a Dream Come True _rvarun7777.mp4
                        )

                )

            [.] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Box Set Cover 2.jpg
                    [1] => Box Set Cover.jpg
                )

            [Breaking Bad Memes] => Array
                (
                    [.] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Breaking Bad Memes_rvarun7777 (1).jpg
                            [1] => Breaking Bad Memes_rvarun7777 (2).jpg
                            [2] => Breaking Bad Memes_rvarun7777 (3).jpg
                            [3] => Breaking Bad Memes_rvarun7777 (4).jpg
                            [4] => Breaking Bad Memes_rvarun7777 (5).jpg
                            [5] => Breaking Bad Memes_rvarun7777 (6).jpg
                            [6] => Breaking Bad Memes_rvarun7777 (7).jpg
                            [7] => Breaking Bad Memes_rvarun7777 (8).jpg
                        )

                )
...
```

Note que a key `'.'` é a lista de arquivos da pasta, todas as outras keys são subdiretórios.

---

Uma variação da segunda opção, caso você queira o `$file['length']` junto com o arquivo você pode mudar algumas linhas e ao invés de `'.'` ser uma lista de arquivos ele virar uma lista de `[ arquivo, length ]`

Ficando assim:

```
require_once 'BDecode.php';
$tor = new BDECODE('file.torrent');

function recursiveDir($path,&$dirbase,$length ){
///                                      ^
///                                    mudei aki    
    if( count($path) > 1 )
    {
        /// criar diretorio com o nome
        $dirname = array_shift($path);
        if( !isset($dirbase[ $dirname ]) ) $dirbase[ $dirname ] = []; /// criar o diretorio caso nao exista
        recursiveDir( $path, $dirbase[ $dirname ], $length );  /// chama novamente para criar subdirs, e adicionar arquivos
        //                                             ^
        //                                            mudei aqui
    }
    else
    {
        /// pode se criar uma key ( Ex.: '.' ou 'files' ) ou apenas array_push no arquivo
        /// array_push( $dirbase, array_shift($path) );
        if( !isset($dirbase['.']) ) $dirbase['.'] = [];
        array_push( $dirbase['.'], [array_shift($path), $length] ); // guarda o arquivo na array de key '.'
        //                                        ^
        //                                      mudei aki, virou array de arquivo, length
    }
}

$dir = [];
foreach( $tor->result['info']['files'] as $file ){
    recursiveDir( $file['path'] , $dir , $file['length'] );
    //                                        ^
    //                                      mudei aki
}
```

A saída desse ficaria +/- assim:

```
Array
(
    [.] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => [rvarun7777 rips] Follow me if you like my encodes!!!!!.txt
                    [1] => 521
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Customized Folder View 1.PNG
                    [1] => 752619
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Customized Folder View.PNG
                    [1] => 938548
                )

        )

    [Extras] => Array
        (
            [[Spoiler] Alternate Ending [Official]] => Array
                (
                    [.] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Breaking Bad' Alternate Ending Is a Dream Come True _rvarun7777.mp4
                                    [1] => 43890886
                                )

                        )

                )
...
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado pela ajuda e e pela explicação.