# Como estruturar um foreach/implode em multi array

Tags: php

Estou com um problema ao lista um array dentro de uma table, estou usando uma função para capturar informações de um arquivo .torrent e exibir em uma tabela, no entanto quando os arquivos estão dentro de uma pasta, a lista fica repetindo o nome da pasta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como poderia contornar esse problema.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope='col'>ARQUIVOS</th>
            <th scope='col'>TAMANHO</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($torrent->result['info']['files'] as $file) {
                echo "
                <tr>
                    <td class='announce-list-file'>" . implode('<tr><td>',$file['path']) . "</td>
                    <td class='announce-list-file'>" . formatSizeUnits($file['length']) . "</td>
                </tr>";
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Um sugestão seria pegar somente o ultimo valor do array `$file['path']` utilizando a função `end()` que retornará sempre o nome do arquivo, assim não irá ter pastas e subpastas na tabela.

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope='col'>ARQUIVOS</th>
        <th scope='col'>TAMANHO</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php foreach($torrent->result['info']['files'] as $file) {      
        echo "
           <tr>
            <td class='announce-list-file'>".end($file['path']) ."</td>
            <td class='announce-list-file'>".$file['length']."</td>
        </tr>";
    }
    ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: obrigado por responder, testei mas não deu certo, não aparece nada, o if esta interpretando como falso e não esta exibindo nada, de uma olhada na minha outra pergunta, adicionei a source no final da pergunta, se você quiser da uma olhada mais a fundo. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/352972/lista-pasta-e-subpastas-em-um-foreach-php